# OSX tmux configuration session open file in vim automatically

Tags: macos, session, vim, configuration-files, tmux

So I have tmux and vim running in iterm2 on OSX. I have a `tmux.conf` file that sources a session in `~/.tmux/` called 'left'. I have successfully loaded this session with three panes. Two panes in a left column and a single pane on the right. I have also managed to successfullly target my upper left pane to run `ls` at startup.

I'm looking for a solution to open a particular file in vim on startup in one of the remaining panes.

The successful ls command is as follows:
`send -t 0 lsa enter`

Assuming the above syntax for the successful ls command, I have tried:
`send -t 1 vim ~/Path/to/my/file enter`

also:

`send -t 1 cmd=vim ~/Path/to/my/file enter`
with no luck

Tmux simply returns it with no spaces *as a string*:
`vim/Users/path/to/file`

It appears it the space is getting lost in the shuffle and no longer delimiting the command from the argument.

Thanks in advance to any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly inserting a `space` should do it:

```
send -t 1 vim space ~/Path/to/my/file enter
```

or you can quote command arguments (I prefer this one):

```
send -t 1 'vim ~/Path/to/my/file' 'enter'
```

Comment: The single quotes did it right off the break! It didn't even cross my mind to quote it. Perfect answer, thanks for your help!